# Recoding multiple variables into a new one leads to strange subtractions

Tags: r

I have several dichotomous variables that I want to recode into a new one. But doing it my way leads to false values. Only the last value is correct and from the others are several missing.

```
set.seed(1)
id <- 1:1000
v1 <- rbinom(1000, 1, 0.05)
v2 <- rbinom(1000, 1, 0.1)
v3 <- rbinom(1000, 1, 0.15)
DF <- data.frame(id, v1, v2, v3)

table(DF$v1) # n = 53
table(DF$v2) # n = 102
table(DF$v3) # n = 154

DF$v_sum <- 0
DF$v_sum[DF$v1 == 1] <-  1
DF$v_sum[DF$v2 == 1] <-  2
DF$v_sum[DF$v3 == 1] <-  3

table(DF$v_sum) # 1 = 43 instead of 53, 2 ist 89 instead of 102 and 3 = 154 is correct
```

What is the proper way to do this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is because value 1 in `v1`, `v2` and `v3` are independent of each other which means there could be more than one 1's in a row.

```
sum(rowSums(DF[-1]) > 1)
#[1] 20
```

As we can see from the above, in 20 rows there are more than one 1's in a row so when you run line 2 (`DF$v_sum[DF$v2 == 1] <-  2`) the `v_sum` for 1st line is over-ridden and when you run line 3 (`DF$v_sum[DF$v3 == 1] <-  3`) it overrides values assigned in line 1 and 2. Hence, giving correct answer only for last value.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I see the issue, but how to handle it properly?

Comment: @Schillerlocke What you want to do if there are two 1's in a row? OR should there never be two 1's in a row at all?